# Moving the wpf button based on mouse position but it blinking

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, wpf-controls

I tried to move the button based on the mouse position but it blinking when the button is moved. Please find the code below,

Below the code for XAML,

```
        <Button Name="Samplebutton"
                PreviewMouseDown="Samplebutton_PreviewMouseDown"
                PreviewMouseUp="Samplebutton_PreviewMouseUp"
                PreviewMouseMove="Samplebutton_PreviewMouseMove"
                Content="Moving" Width="100" Height="35"/>
```

CS,

```
    private bool m_IsPressed = false;

    private void Samplebutton_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
        {
            m_IsPressed = true;
        }
        else
        {
            m_IsPressed = false;
        }
    }

    private void Samplebutton_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        m_IsPressed = false;
    }

    private void Samplebutton_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_IsPressed)
        {
            TranslateTransform transform = new TranslateTransform();
            transform.X = Mouse.GetPosition(sender as Button).X;
            transform.Y = Mouse.GetPosition(sender as Button).Y;
            this.Samplebutton.RenderTransform = transform;
        }
    }
```

Any one please provide your suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "flickering" is caused by the transform in your `PreviewMouseMove` handler.

You are transforming the X and Y positions of the control, using the position of the mouse relative to your Button control, which will change every time your transform is applied. Every time the button position changes, your `Mouse.GetPosition(sender as Button).X` & `Y` will return different values, causing the button to change position again, and so on.

One way around this would be to get the mouse position from a parent element (e.g. `Grid`, `Canvas` with a fixed position):

```
<Grid Name="myGrid">
    <Button Name="Samplebutton"
            PreviewMouseDown="Samplebutton_PreviewMouseDown"
            PreviewMouseUp="Samplebutton_PreviewMouseUp"
            PreviewMouseMove="Samplebutton_PreviewMouseMove"
            Content="Moving" Width="100" Height="35"/>
</Grid>
```

and

```
private void Samplebutton_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_IsPressed)
        {
            TranslateTransform transform = new TranslateTransform();
            transform.X = Mouse.GetPosition(myGrid).X;
            transform.Y = Mouse.GetPosition(myGrid).Y;
            this.Samplebutton.RenderTransform = transform;
        }
    }
```

This won't be the prettiest thing in the world, as it will "grab" the button from the top left, but you can adapt the position to obtain your desired behaviour.

Good luck.

Edit: If you don't want to explicitly name the element you wish to use for the relative position, you should be able to select the immediate parent by querying the `sender` object:

```
transform.X = Mouse.GetPosition((sender as Button).Parent as FrameworkElement).X;
```

Comment: Thanks, i will check and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void button_PreviewMouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        button.CaptureMouse();
    }

    private void button_PreviewMouseUp_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        button.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }

    private void button_PreviewMouseMove_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (button.IsMouseCaptured)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(button, e.GetPosition(this).X);
            Canvas.SetTop(button, e.GetPosition(this).Y);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your trying, but i don't want to acheive this by Canvas.